# how to determine a time for fetching data in react native

Tags: react-native

I wrote a method in react native and that fetches some data from a server. and I make a modal to show this message: "Receiving Data!".Now I want to know how can I determine a time for this operation. for example, after 10 seconds, I show a message as "The internet connection is not connected!".
thank advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function when you fetch
ShowAlertWithDelay=()=>{

```
setTimeout(function(){

  //Put All Your Code Here, Which You Want To Execute After Some Delay Time.
  Alert.alert("Alert Shows After 5 Seconds of Delay.")

}, 5000);
```

}